# Why does this swap using simple addition and subtraction won't overflow?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I was under the impression that only swap using X-OR would work when we are providing inputs that are close to max limit of integer. Surprisingly this simple swap using addition and subtraction is working with those inputs too.

```
#include <iostream>

void simple_swap(int &x, int &y) {
    x += y;
    y = x - y;
    x -= y;
}

int main() {
    int a = 10; int b = 15;

    /* Testing integer overflow, sum has 1 bit outside of 4-bytes integer limit */
    a = 0xFFFFFFFF;     // a is 2^32-1 = 4294967295
    b = 0xFFFFFFFE;     // b is 2^32-2 = 4294967294

    std::cout << "Before swap " << "a = " << (unsigned int)a << ", b=" << (unsigned int)b << std::endl;
    simple_swap(a, b);
    std::cout << "After swap " << "a = " << (unsigned int)a << ", b=" << (unsigned int)b << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2013. If you are using a different compiler and the code does not work as showed in output let me know in comments.

I'm interested in knowing the reason behind this. Is compiler replacing the code with something else?

Comment: It's undefined behavior if it overflows, so everything can happen, including it seemingly working. Also even xor-swapping is broken, use a temp variable please.

Comment: Undefined behaviour is allowed to work normally. However, the common wrap-around behaviour works.

Comment: `a = 0xFFFFFFFF;` - what value does `a` contain after this statement executes?

Comment: @immibis, An implementation-defined value that, in all likelihood, is -1.

Comment: Indeed. And `-1 + -2` doesn't overflow, nor does `-3 - -2`, nor does `-3 - -1`. So the undefined behaviour is not in the swap itself.

Comment: @immibis not with the numbers in his example, but the risk is there if he uses really big/small numbers.

Comment: @immibis, right. I think that's a correct answer. The way I was trying to overflow was incorrect.

Comment: @RaphaelMiedl would you please explain the risk of using really small numbers? Thanks.

Comment: @Atique it's the same as big numbers. If you got numbers close to the max value you can overflow if you got values close to the minimum you can underflow.

Comment: @immibis, You're right; I didn't read the question well enough after the title.

Answer (score 7):

## Swap using addition

Even if it seems to work it's a bad idea.

```
void simple_swap(int &x, int &y) {
    x += y;
    y = x - y;
    x -= y;
}
```

if both `x` and `y` are really big or really small you'll get integer overflow/underflow which is undefined behavior. That means even if it seems to work for you there aren't any guarantees that it will work for anyone else or even when you compile it the next time. It can just break from one moment to the other.

## Swap using xor

Also just for the record, using xor for swapping is broken too, for a whole different reason though.

```
void simple_swap(int &x, int &y) {
    x ^= y;
    y ^= x;
    x ^= y;
}
```

works most of the time but if you were to try and swap a variable with itself it would break:

```
simple_swap(a, a);

void simple_swap(int &x, int &y) { // both x and y refer to the same variable (a).
    x ^= y; // both variables will be 0 after this statement.
    y ^= x;
    x ^= y;
}
```

Now swapping a variable with itself might seem dumb and unlikely but you don't always know. It could be two pointers that just happen to point to the same variable and suddenly you got a weird bug. To make sure that it'd always work you'd have to make it overly complicated and test that both parameters aren't actually the same.

```
void simple_swap(int &x, int &y) {
    if ( x != y) {
        x ^= y;
        y ^= x;
        x ^= y;
    }
}
```

harder to read than such a simple function should be and not as simple as one thinks at first.

## The correct way

Just use the simple and easy correct way, don't try to be clever:

```
void simple_swap(int &x, int &y) {
    int temp = x;
    x = y;
    y = temp;
}
```

Swapping is simple, every compiler will be able to optimize it to the best version.

Answer (score 0):

Working through the operations, the mathematical values result in a correct swap, disregarding the possibility of overflow.

The operations used, in 2's complement, maintain the invariant that the value is the "true mathematical value" modulo 2^(word_size_in_bytes).

Since there is only one residue modulo 2^(word-size-in-bytes) of any "true mathematical value", the swap is guaranteed to exchange the values (whatever they may represent).

Of course, 2's complement is not guaranteed by the C or C++ standards. It's just what's done in >99.9999% of CPUs.

Comment: Yes, most CPUs have consistent behavior on signed integer overflow (behavior that's not guaranteed by the language standard). But an optimizing compiler can and will generate code that's inconsistent with what you might expect. For example, with gcc the output of `int n = INT_MAX; puts(n + 1 > n ? "yes" : "no");` varies depending on the optimization level.

Comment: Well, IMHO gcc should have an option `-fno-indefensible-math` that prevents such optimizations.

Comment: The behavior of signed integer overflow is explicitly undefined by the C standard. I think what you're advocating is a gcc option that would cause it to compile a C-like language in which signed integers do not overflow, but wrap around similarly to unsigned integers. I wouldn't object to such an option (but if it were up to me its name wouldn't include the word "indefensible").